# Fast Tranfering my Wordpress site to another server

Tags: plugins, php, server, ftp

I am transferring my WordPress site. I need to transfer all the content to my new server from old one. I don't have that enough bandwidth that i can first FTP to my local PC and than again FTP to the new server. So i request people right here to help me find out some sophisticated technique. All helpful suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you don't have "enough bandwidth" to transfer files via FTP to your local computer and then to the new server?  Where is your bandwidth bottleneck?  At some point, you'll need to transfer those files.  I suppose you could FTP directly from old server to new, if you have shell access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Duplicator plugin, Its clone your total site and easily transfer to  another server. http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: This plugin only helps you to run a duplicate copy of your website offline. It cant be used to transfer to a another server.

Answer (score 0):

[VaultPress](http://vaultpress.com/) and [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) are two paid solutions that can be used to backup your site and restore to a new location without transferring anything to your local computer.